# Is it considered okay (best practice) to access a child's state?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a parent component which has many child components (the child component is an empty div with a coloured background).

I want to change the child's colour but want to make sure I'm making it a different colour than it already is - eg. if the child is blue, I want to change it to another colour that isn't blue.

To do this I am using a prop to set the inital colour and saving this prop to the child's state.

When I then click on the div to change the colour I want to access the current colour of the div so that I can exclude it from the selection to of course to choose from

1) Is this considered okay to do in react? 
2) If it is - can someone please explain how I can access a child's state?
3) If this isn't a great approach how should I tackle this problem?

```
class ColourBoxes extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

    }

    this.newColour = this.newColour.bind(this)
}

static defaultProps = {
    colours: ['#ff3860', '#498afb', '#fa8142', '#09c372', '#9166cc', '#ffdd57', '#ff4088']
}

newColour(oldColour) {

}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <Box colour={'#09c372'} ref="child"/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

```
   class Box extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {currColour: this.props.colour}
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="Box" style={{backgroundColor: this.props.colour}}></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are changing the color of the box by clicking on the box itself, then just pass the currColour as a parameter to the parent function and in that function just filter out that color.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach fits in the REACT way: the state of a component should be used just for the component itself, and, even if possible, it should be accessed by other components (I'm not even sure if you could end up having async issues by doing so).

In your case, you should [Lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), as REACT official doc recommend.

Basically, you keep the information about the `<Box>` color inside your `<ColorBoxes>` component: any time the state in `<ColorBoxes>` will change, new props will arrive to your `<Box>`s component, making them changing the color.

Moreover, by having the state in `<ColorBoxes>`, you can make a check if the new color is the same as the current one.

Notice that this approach is worth it if your click handler is implemented in `<ColorBoxes>`; instead, in case it would be in `<Box>`.. Well, then you would just use `this.state.currColour` to check if the new color differs from the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked if it is best practices, the answer is NO. The state is meant to be consumed inside the component itself. For sharing data across components props should be used. You can either use Redux or Context API for your purpose.